# Custom home page and custom index page? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom `home.php` design only for my homepage, also I have an `index.php` that made for page like: `http://example.com/page/11`

my problem is that for this page `http://example.com/page/11` WordPress load `home.php` how can I load `index.php` for this page?

Note: I don't want to use custom blog page like : `http://example.com/blog/page/11`

Note: I try front-page.php and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Add create a **custom-page.php** file inside your theme folder. Then add the following code on the top of that file.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custompage */ ?>
```

Then select the **Custompage** while create the page or edit the page. That page will appear with the design you have added in **custom-page.php**.

Comment: it's make a custom page. I want `http://example.com/` load my custom code only for home page of my site. but it load on other page like `http://example.com/page/11`